# Unrecognized Selector Sent to Instance error on array

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I'm getting this error code "[__NSArrayM myNameChoices]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c99060" on the self.mySelectedCell = currentRow.myNameChoices; line. I'm not exactly sure I why.

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyDataChoices *currentRow = self.arrayNames[indexPath.row];
    //unrecognized selector sent to instance 
    self.mySelectedCell = currentRow.myNameChoices;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"unwindSegueAction" sender:self];

}
```

The array arrayNames being filled:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.myTableView.delegate = self;
    self.myTableView.dataSource = self;
    //does not work with more than one array in the array
    self.arrayNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[[MyDataChoices itemWithNewName:@"Apples"]]],
                       [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[[MyDataChoices itemWithNewName:@"Oranges"]]], nil];


}
```

The .h code containing mySelected cell

```
@interface ChoicesTableViewController : UITableViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *mySelectedCell;

@end
```

The .h code containing myDataChoices objects

```
@interface MyDataChoices : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *myNameChoices;

+ (MyDataChoices *)itemWithNewName:(NSString *)myNameChoices;

@end
```

The .m code containing myDataChoices objects

```
@implementation MyDataChoices
+ (MyDataChoices *)itemWithNewName:(NSString *)myNameChoices
{
    MyDataChoices *object = [[MyDataChoices alloc] init];

    object.myNameChoices = myNameChoices;


    return object;
}

@end
```

Thanks for the information!

Comment: Show the code that initializes and populates the `arrayNames` array on the first block of code you posted.

Comment: FYI - this line: `MyDataChoices *object = [MyDataChoices alloc];` is missing the required call to `init`.

Comment: the lack of an alloc] init] makes me twitch. i think rmaddy's comment is right. also, you can simplify your array allocation this way: self.arrayNames = @[ element1, element2 ]... where @[] is shorthand for an array. so you can do arrays of arrays by doing @[ @[obj], @[obj] ]

Comment: I have shown the code for the array. Note: It is a 2d array I have more plans for later.

Comment: You created an array of arrays of `MyDataChoices` objects. The line that crashes assumes you just have an array of `MyDataChoices` objects.

Comment: If you need to structure your data this way, multidimensional arrays are a lot of work to manage in obj-c. When I have to work with this type of structure, I use a dictionary object and add the arrays to the dict with keys identifying what the array holds. It plays nicely with tables and looping etc. Also unrecognized selector sent to instance is pretty much compiler speak saying tried to do something with an object that is known but not initialised. I'd put breakpoints and just check that all your arrays are populated correctly. Just thoughts, hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

`self.arrayNames` is returning `NSMutableArray`s, not `MyDataChoices` objects, as you're expecting. The error is because `NSMutableArrays` do not have a `myNameChoices` property.

Try something like this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.arrayNames = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [MyDataChoices itemWithNewName:@"Apples"],
                       [MyDataChoices itemWithNewName:@"Oranges"], nil];
```